# My Flawed Algorithm: returns ($desired_result - 1) or ($desired_result + 1)

Tags: php

I'm creating a script to add recipes to a database.  For my add_recipe form, I'd like to give users an option to add as many ingredients as they'd like.

The following code is just something I came up with for testing purposes, since I've never tried this before:

```
<?php
$ingredient = '(another ingredient)';
$num_ingredients = $_REQUEST['select'];
?>
<html>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="onchange.php">
<select name="select" onchange="javascript: document.form1.submit();">
  <option value=1>Add 1 Ingredient</option>
  <option value=2>Add 2 Ingredients</option>
  <option value=3>Add 3 Ingredients</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
while ($num_ingredients <= 3) {
  $num_ingredients++;
  echo $ingredient;
  echo '<br />';
}
?>
```

The problem is...my code, lol.  For example...

option value=1 returns:

```
(another ingredient)
(another ingredient)
```

option value=3 returns:

```
(another ingredient)
```

Can someone steer me in the right direction?  Any help is greaaaatly appreciated 8)

Comment: The `<=` means that you want a max of 4. It's much more readable to just do `< 4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a counter variable.

```
$count = 0;
if ($num_ingredients > 3) 
   $num_ingredients = 3;
while ($count < $num_ingredients ) {
  $count++;
  echo $ingredient;
  echo '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The section here needs to change.  $num_ingredients comes from the select as 1, 2 and 3... your loop is basically saying while $num_ingredients is less than or equal to 3.  Selecting 1 will give you three loops, 2 will give you 2 loops and 3 will give you 1 loop.  You need to have a counter instead, i.e.

```
<?php
for ($count = 0; $count < $num_ingredients; $count++) 
{
    echo $ingredient;
    echo '<br />';
}
?>
```